# Accessing Python instance variables with __dict__- Is it wrong?

Tags: python

If I want to access the list of instance variables of an object, I can call `myObject.__dict__.keys()`.  I want to use this attribute to print out all instance variables of an object.  I am hesitant to do this because `__dict__` is a "secret" attribute, and I do not understand what [this footnote](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#id2) means.

So is it wrong to use `myObject.__dict__`?

Comment: You might(?) prefer the `vars(myObject)` stylistically, but that's orthogonal to your question.  It gives the same __dict__.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What the footnote means is that you shouldn't try to access `__dict__` directly but instead check if the feature/behavior you want is available.

So instead of doing something like:

```
if "__some_attribute__" in obj.__dict__:
    # do stuff
```

you should instead do:

```
try:
    obj.some_action_i_want_to_do(...)
except AttributeError:
    # doesn't provide the functionality I want
```

The reasons for this are because different objects might provide different internal references to a certain action but still provide the desired output.

If you want to list the "internals" for the sake of debugging and inspecting the current object, then [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) is the right way to do it.

Comment: But `dir()` only gives the names; `__dict__` also gives the objects themselves.

Answer (score 6):

That footnote is in reference to the `__dict__` attribute of a *module*. The `__dict__` attribute of an object carries no such warning ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__dict__#object.__dict__)).

Comment: There are alike warnings for objects when accessors, metaclasses, or slots are used. Exceptions are so cheap in Python that they are used to end iteration in generators.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`dir`](http://docs.python.org/functions.html#dir) function to list all attributes of an object.

Answer (score 3):

Using it for things like printing out members for debugging should be fine.  But if that's all you're doing, check out pretty print.

http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html

The main problem with `__dict__`, is it violates the implied visibility rules of objects that python has.

Comment: `__dict__` is hackery. It's powerful and dangerous, and you don't *need* it at all for programming. That's why. That it violates visibility is just one part of it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out pprint.  I always wondered if there was an easy way to emulate iPython-style collection printing.

Comment: This `__dict__` issue seems like a bit of a rabbit hole but I'd like to understand it better.  What do you mean by implied visibility rules?

Comment: The problem with `__dict__` is that it leads to the idea that `obj.__dict__['x']` is the same as `obj.x`, which is completely wrong. The difference is that `obj.x` invokes descriptors but `__dict__` doesnt.